# Mean js - display updates in real time

Tags: javascript, meanjs

I'm new to `meanjs`, I just created a new module for adding products. These products are displayed in the home page. But the display in home page is not getting updated `real time`. I just added new product in one tab, and the products list in the other tab need to be refreshed to see the change. How can this be done at `real time`  ?

Edit:

By updation I meant is, when ever a new record is been added to database, the product display should update in realtime. Now I need to refresh the page to see the newly added product.
My code is

Client

```
        $http.get('/latestproducts').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.latestproducts = data;
          })
```

Server

```
exports.getlatestProducts = function(req, res) {
    Product.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, products) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(products);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is updation? edit - can you post some of your code, or some more detail on the problem? this is hard to answer as it stands. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean browser tabs, mean.js won't do if fo you. You can use sockets to inform server that changes were made and then broadcast message to all active tabs to refresh data. You can also try window.blur/window.focus events to reload data.

If you have list of products and product form on the same page, you have 2 options:

- add saved item to your local collection after you save poduct and recive success message from server.
- Update local collection(get list of objects from the server) after you save poduct and recive success message from server.

Comment: Thank you. Can you find some sample code for using socket with mean js ?

Comment: I dont, but my favourite lib is http://socket.io/.  Here is tutorial : https://vexxhost.com/blog/mean-socket-io-integration-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Mike, Thats a nice tutorial, but I'm stuck with an error 'Failed to instantiate module btford.socket-io' I installed the angular-socket-io using bower 'bower install angular-socket-io'. Did you get any error like this ?

Comment: \config\env\all.js - here you need to add your dependency. Then inject dependency in the angular module, that should be all

Answer (score 0):

I just released [angular-socket-resource](https://github.com/michaschwab/angular-socket-resource). Once you use a service instead of performing the http request manually, you can use that to automatically listen for socket.io updates that will update your local data.